# Data Duplication solution using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, business-intelligence

I have a problem about duplication of data for example;

```
PIN       OwnerNum      Effectivity Year    Total Tax
pin123    1003          2014                2,000.00
pin123    1002          2009                3,000.00
pin456    4002          2015                1,500.00
pin456    4001          2014                  900.00
```

I have two columns in my table  and this is my desired output in SQL query;

```
PIN      OwnerNum      Effectivity Year    Total Tax
pin123    1003          2014                2,000.00
pin456    4002          2015                1,500.00
```

I really find this hard because i'm conducting BI report for  Real Property Tax System that has no future or past entities  for effectivity year.To simplify the data, I created a module whose effectivity year is <=2015. I want to fetch the highest effectivity year only per pin and owner.Thanks for all your help.

Comment: what is the goal ? you want to get the max value of total tax in <=2015 ?

Comment: what are you looking for? the largest total tax per effectivity year? just any random record per year?

Comment: my goal is to fetch data whose effectivity year is <= 2015.

Comment: so what happens with pin456 at year 2014? is it the largest year by pin?

Comment: On the other hand, I'm about to select top 50 tax payer of year 2015.

Comment: ah it should be ignored in computations John Ruddell

Comment: whats happening in my computations is it sums all data whose effectivity year is <=2015, which is not accurate.

Comment: @яша I want to fetch the highest effectivity year only per pin and owner.Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Basically largest effectivity year by Pin

Comment: The "greatest N per group" problem is a pain in the butt with MySQL.  Most RDBMSs have analytic functions like ROW_NUMBER() that make it easier, but MySQL lacks these.  [This blog](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) covers some of the more common solutions.  Beyond that, you're going to have to post your SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

First find the Max `Effectivity Year` per `PIN`. Then join the result with your table on `PIN` and `Effectivity Year` to get the result.

```
select PIN,OwnerNum,`Effectivity Year`,Total Tax 
from yourtable A
Inner join 
(
select PIN,max(`Effectivity Year`) as Max_Effectivity_Year
from Yourtable 
Where  `effectivity year` <= 2015
Group by PIN
) B 
ON A.PIN = B.PIN
AND A.`Effectivity Year` = B.Max_Effectivity_Year
```